# optuna import successful but cannot import optuna.integration.lightgbm

Tags: python, import, optuna

I am a beginner of Python who is stacked by basic task.
I am using Jupyter lab and python 3.10 after deleting all the files or PATH associated with anaconda, which did not work well.

```
import optuna
```

works without an issue, but

```
import optuna.integration.lightgbm as lgb
```

raises the following error:

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import optuna.integration.lightgbm as lgb

......

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/ctypes/**init**.py:374, in CDLL.**init**(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
371 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
373 if handle is None:
--> 374     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
375 else:
376     self._handle = handle

OSError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file)

Comment: Could you import lightgbm correctly? Usually, I install lightgbm via `conda`: `conda install lightgbm`, to fix such an error.

Comment: I eventually solved this problem by creating another environment. Thank you.